# How much time does Cardano-graphql take to initialize?

Tags: cardano-db-sync, cardano-graphql

I had configured db-sync and it is synchronizing. I had also started the Cardano-graphql. However, the message seems to be struck at

> "msg":"Initializing. This can take a few minutes..."

Will this proceed only after db-synch is fully synchronized?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it should as soon as the `cardano-db-sync` is synced. It depends generally on the available resources. It takes usually few days to complete.